# Is it possible to set TTL of each element in map of different columns using single update command in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, endianness, ttl

suppose the table name : company_employee

```
select * from company_employee ;
```

```
company_id  | company_name | employee_id_name_map         | employee_id_department_map
------------+--------------+------------------------------+---------------------------
123         |      abc     | {'1': 'john'} ,{'2': 'jack'} | {'1': 'tech'} ,{'2': 'hr'}
```

Here I wanted to set TTL for a **employee_id_name_map** element **"{'1': 'john'}"** as **30** and for **employee_id_department_map** element **"{'1': 'tech'}"** as **40** is there any way to update both elements using single Cassandra command ?

I have tried by setting ttl for individual element in map using individual command like below

```
UPDATE company_employee USING TTL 30 SET employee_id_name_map['1']='john' WHERE company_id='123' and company_name = 'abc';
```

```
UPDATE company_employee USING TTL 40 SET employee_id_department_map['1']='tech' WHERE company_id='123' and company_name = 'abc';
```

using above cassandra commands its worked good , but i wanted to get in a single cassandra write , any good suggestion helps me alot ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't set different TTLs in one CQL statement.  But you can use batches to combine several commands into a single Cassandra write (if you work on the same partition key). Like this:

```
BEGIN BATCH
UPDATE company_employee USING TTL 30 SET employee_id_name_map['1']='john' WHERE company_id='123' and company_name = 'abc';
UPDATE company_employee USING TTL 40 SET employee_id_department_map['1']='tech' WHERE company_id='123' and company_name = 'abc';
APPLY BATCH;
```